# java.lang.NullPointerException when using getStringArray

Tags: java, android

I am working on an app that will generate a treasure list.

This is my string array to store the list into:

```
String treasure[] = {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
        "", "", "", "", ""} ;
```

This is how I am filling the values

```
treasure[0] = coinvalue + " copper pieces";
```

This is where I send the compiled list to the next part:

```
Bundle treasurelist = new Bundle();
        treasurelist.putStringArray("loot", treasure);
        Intent a = new Intent(TreasureGen.this, Treasure_Results.class);
        a.putExtras(treasurelist);
        startActivity(a);
```

This is where I am picking up the list in the next stage:

```
public class Treasure_Results extends ListActivity {
        String getTreasure[] ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle gettreasurelist = getIntent().getExtras();
        getTreasure = gettreasurelist.getStringArray("loot");
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Treasure_Results.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getTreasure));


    }
}
```

And this is the error code I am getting:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.giraffelitis.ptindustries.dungeonmasterassistant.Treasure_Results.onCreate(Treasure_Results.java:24)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5431)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and when i click on the link it sends me to this line of code

```
getTreasure = gettreasurelist.getStringArray("loot");
```

As this is only my second day of trying to code in Java I have no idea what to do ... I have looked through the forums trying to find the solution and there are some similar problems however I can't find the problem in mine off of those answers.

**UPDATE**

I have tried the suggestion below ... here is the TreasureGen activity code that applies to this function.

```
roll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    treasurecr = counter;
                    int d100;
                    int coinvalue;

                    String treasure[] = {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
                            "", "", "", "", ""} ;
                    Bundle treasurelist = new Bundle();
                    treasurelist.putStringArray("loot", treasure);
                    Intent a = new Intent(TreasureGen.this, Treasure_Results.class);
                    a.putExtras(treasurelist);
                    startActivity(a);

                    Intent openStartPoint = new                   Intent("com.giraffelitis.ptindustries.TREASUREGEN2");
                    startActivity(openStartPoint);
                }
            });
```

and here is my entire Treasure_Results activity

```
public class Treasure_Results extends ListActivity {
        String getTreasure[] ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle treasurelist = getIntent().getExtras();
        getTreasure = treasurelist.getStringArray("loot");
        System.out.println("getTreasure = " + getTreasure);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Treasure_Results.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getTreasure));

    }
    //@Override
    //public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // do something with the data
    //}
}
```

and here is my error log as to what is in getTreasure array

```
08-24 17:02:34.040  25764-25764/com.giraffelitis.ptindustries.dungeonmasterassistant I/System.out﹕ getTreasure = [Ljava.lang.String;@429bcae0
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: So `gettreasurelist` is probably `null` here. I would check if `getIntent().getExtras()` is returning `null` and go from there.

Comment: Yes, put a breakpoint there and check it.

Comment: Also check if either `treasurelist` or `treasure` are `null` in the first Activity.

Comment: Breakpoint depends on the IDE. You could also use a simple if statement.

Comment: `if (gettreasurelist == null) { System.out.println("gtl is null"); }`

Comment: im not finding anywhere that its displaying the System.out.println in the debug screens

Comment: If you are in Eclipse, check LogCat View.

Comment: ok found it ... it is showing gtl as null

Comment: I've gone through more forums ... rewritten the code a few times trying to fix the null error ... The way shown above seems to be the way it's worked the best out of everything ... any suggestions on how to get rid of the null ... Because everything works except that

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transmit array String between two activities you can use the following code (in you initial activity):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
in.putExtra("loot", treasure);
```

Meanwhile, in your activity where you want to process the array:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String treasure[] = intent.getStringArrayExtra("loot");
```

Comment: i gave this one a shot and it pulled up null the same as the code posted above. it showed the results as null where as the code posted above gives the weird lang string results in the array

Comment: can you make available ur project somewhere?